# I can't get the join function in mysql to work

Tags: mysql, joomla

Can someone please tell me what the syntax error is here:

```
`SELECT T.id,T.vmProductID,T.name AS Course,C.title AS Category FROM j25_lms_tests AS T LEFT JOIN j25_lms_categories AS C ON C.id = T.catid WHERE T.published=1 AND T.vmProductID IN() ORDER BY T.ordering`
```

This is the main code from script:

```
'SELECT T.id,T.vmProductID,T.name AS Course,C.title AS Category FROM #__lms_tests AS T 
        LEFT JOIN #__lms_categories AS C ON C.id = T.catid
        WHERE T.published=1 AND T.vmProductID IN($vmProductIds) $Catwhere 
        ORDER BY T.ordering";'
```

Please can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is in `T.vmProductID IN()` the values are missing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `IN`clause has no values:

```
T.vmProductID IN()
```

Comment: Thank so much Jens